# pandas drop last group element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["a","b","c","d","e", "f","g","h"], 'col2': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]})` that looks like

**Input:**

```
 col1 col2
0   a   1
1   b   1
2   c   1
3   d   2
4   e   2
5   f   3
6   g   3
7   h   3
```

I want to drop the last row bases off of grouping "col2" which would look like...

**Expected Output:**

```
 col1 col2
0   a   1
1   b   1
3   d   2
5   f   3
6   g   3
```

I wrote `df.groupby('col2').tail(1)` which gets me what I want to delete but when I try to write `df.drop(df.groupby('col2').tail(1))` I get an axis error. What would be a solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like `duplicated` would work:

```
df[df.duplicated('col2', keep='last') | 
   (~df.duplicated('col2', keep=False))  # this is to keep all single-row groups
  ]
```

Or with your approach, you should drop the index:

```
# this would also drop all single-row groups
df.drop(df.groupby('col2').tail(1).index)
```

---

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    b     1
3    d     2
5    f     3
6    g     3
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
df.groupby('col2', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1,:]).reset_index(drop=True)
```